# Visual Studio Code for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded and installed VS Code, C# extensions & .NET Core SDK for Windows.

Have followed the instructions in the video provided.

But when I execute "dotnet new" nothing happens & it is not throwing any errors as well.

From the documentation, ideally it should create a sample program.cs

Am I missing something??

**UPDATE**
Now it says following

[image]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/dotnet

Answer (score -1):

What you say your are doing sounds good. If you are able to type the dotnet command in the Command Prompt without error messages, it should be installed fine.

If running the following commands do not give you a Prohram.cs file in %HOMEPATH%\HelloWorld, you can type `dotnet -h`, what is the output of that command?

```
cd %HOMEPATH%
mkdir HelloWorld 
cd .\HelloWorld
dotnet new -t Console
dir .
```

Comment: I tried all these commands, all executed without error, but the default code for program.cs was not created. May be issue with PATH, will check that..

Comment: If there was a problem with the PATH, you probably did not find dotnet command and that would give an error message. At which location do you try to create a new project? Are you sure the user have permission at the location?

Comment: I think the problem is something different, because as I can create folder using mkdir and it is getting created, I think the required permissions are there.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: @TeisLindemark, thanks for your code, it says "Could not find the preLaunchTask 'build'." I will search around it now...